# Integration question with limit

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm trying to solve the following question and have some ideas (please see below) but having a hard time trying to "connect all the dots" and using all the given information.

> let $f:\left[a,b\right]\to\mathbb{R}$ continuously differentiable,
>
> let $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ continous such that
> $\left|\int_{a}^{x}g\left(t\right)\,dt\right|\leqslant M$ for all
> $x\in\mathbb{R}$ ($M>0$ is constant).
>
> Show that
> $\underset{n\to\infty}{\lim}\int_{a}^{b}f\left(x\right)g\left(nx\right)\,dx=0$.

---

**First, g is continous we have G(x) such that:**

$\forall x\in\left[a,b\right]\,\,\,G'\left(x\right)=g\left(x\right)$

**Given $\left|\int_{a}^{x}g\left(t\right)\,dt\right|\leqslant M$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$  we can substitue $t=nx$ and get:**
$\left|n\int_{a}^{x}g\left(nx\right)\,dnx\right|\leqslant M\,\,\,\,\,\Rightarrow\,\,\,\,\,\left|\int_{a}^{x}g\left(nt\right)\,dnx\right|\leqslant\frac{M}{n}\,\,\,\,\,\Rightarrow\,\,\,\,\,-\frac{M}{n}\leqslant\left[G\left(nx\right)\right]_{a}^{x}\leqslant\frac{M}{n}$

we also know that $f'(x)$ is continuous $\Rightarrow$ bounded

**Finally, we can use integration by parts:**

$\int_{a}^{b}f\left(x\right)g\left(nx\right)\,dx=\left[f\left(x\right)\cdot\frac{G\left(nx\right)}{n}\right]_{a}^{b}-\int_{a}^{b}f'\left(x\right)\frac{G\left(nx\right)}{n}\,dx$

and we want to prove that:

$\forall\varepsilon>0\,\,\,\exists N>0\,\,\,\forall n>N\,\,\,\Rightarrow\left|\int_{a}^{b}f\left(x\right)g\left(nx\right)\right|<\varepsilon$

Comment: The substitution $t=nx$ chages the limits of integration.

Comment: This looks like a restricted version of Riemann Lebesgue Lemma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your notation we have $|G(x)| \le M$ for every $ x \in \mathbb R$.

Following your strategy:
$$
\begin{split}
0 \le \left|\int_a^b f(x) g(nx) \operatorname d x  \right|&=\left|f(b)\frac{G(nb)}{n} -f(a) \frac{G(na)}{n}-\int_a^b f'(x) \frac{G(nx)}{n} \operatorname d x  \right| \\
&\le \left| f(b) \frac{G(nb)}{n}\right| + \left| f(a) \frac{G(na)}{n}\right| + \left| \int_a^b f'(x) \frac{G(nx)}{n} \operatorname d x\right|\\
&\le \left| f(b)\right|  \frac{M}{n}+ \left| f(a)\right|  \frac{M}{n} +\int_a^b  \left|  f'(x)\frac{G(nx)}{n}\right|  \operatorname d x \\
&\le \left(\left| f(b)\right|+ \left| f(b)\right|   +\int_a^b  \left|  f'(x)\right|  \operatorname d x \right)\frac{M}{n}  \\
&\le \left(\left| f(b)\right|+ \left| f(b)\right|   + \max_{[a,b]}{|f'|} (b-a) \right)\frac{M}{n} \to 0 \\
\end{split} 
$$

For the squeeze theorem we can conclude that $\lim\limits_{n \to +\infty}\displaystyle\int_a^b f(x) g(nx) \operatorname d x  = 0 $.

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you explain please why given $\left|\int_{a}^{x}g\left(t\right)\,dt\right|\leqslant M$ we can determine that also $\left|\int_{3}^{\frac{a}{n}}g\left(t\right)\,dt\right|\leqslant M$ as you noted? Isn't that out of the integral limits?

Comment: OK maybe I got it, did you mean that: $\left|\int_{\frac{a}{n}}^{\frac{b}{n}}g\left(t\right)\,dt\right|=\left|\int_{\frac{a}{n}}^{a}g\left(t\right)\,dt+\int_{a}^{\frac{b}{n}}g\left(t\right)\,dt\right|\leqslant\left|\int_{\frac{a}{n}}^{a}g\left(t\right)\,dt\right|+\left|\int_{a}^{\frac{b}{n}}g\left(t\right)\,dt\right|\leqslant2M$?

Comment: Yes, you can use $a$ as the inferior limit. In general $$\int_a^b f(x) \operatorname d x = \int_a^c f(x) f(x) \operatorname dx + \int_c ^ b f(x) \operatorname d x $$ even if $c \not \in (a,b)$

Comment: I edited the answer. Is it now clearer?

Comment: Yes, thank you! One more thing still bothers me though: what if $\text{∫}baf(x)g(nx)dx<0$? for example $-2<1$ but $\left|-2\right|\nleq\left|1\right|$

Comment: I used another approach, closer to your intuition. Does this convince you?

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! One last thing: given $\left|G\left(x\right)\right|=\left|\int_{a}^{x}g\left(t\right)\,dt\right|\leqslant M$, is it trivial that $\left|G\left(nx\right)\right|=\left|\int_{a}^{nx}g\left(t\right)\,dt\right|\leqslant M$? No need further explenation/formalization?

Comment: As I understand, does exist a constant $M$ such that for every $y \in \mathbb R$ we have $|G(y)| \le M$ (so the function $G$ is bounded), hence $|G(nx)|\le M$ for every $n \in \mathbb N$ and $x \in \mathbb R$

Comment: Why is $|f(a)|\leq |f(b)|$?

Comment: @Parasect Where did I use it? I only used triangle inequality